# Is there any way a C/C++ compiler can inline a C-Callback Function?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-optimization, inlining

Given a typical function that takes a C-Functionpointer as a callback like C-Stdlib `qsort()`, can any compiler optimize the code using inlining? I think it can not, is this correct?

```
int cmp(void* pa, void* pb) { /*...*/ }
int func() {
  int vec[1000];
  qsort(vec, 1000, sizeof(int), &cmp);
}
```

Ok, `qsort()` is a function from an external library, but I don't think even [LTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-time_optimization) would help here, right?

But what if I have `my_qsort()` defined in the same compilation unit, would then inlining be  possible for the compiler?

```
int cmp(void* pa, void* pb) { /*...*/ }
void my_qsort(int* vec, int n, int sz, (void*)(void*,void*)) { /* ... */ }
int func() {
  int vec[1000];
  my_qsort(vec, 1000, sizeof(int), &cmp);
}
```

Does that make any difference? I think the use of the *C-function pointer* as a callback is the factor that prevents the compiler from inlining. Correct?

(I just want to make sure I understand why I should use *Functors* in C++)

Comment: Have you tried it? I've heard that GCC can inline through function pointers.

Comment: If I take gcc `-S` output, and rewrite it to inline whatever I want (suppose I know assembler) ... am I (paired with gcc) an optimizing compiler (*capable of inlining callbacks*)?

Comment: @a.l.: No, I have not tried. Good, point. But when I discover it can not, what about *theory*? @pmg: But can you? Pulling out the `qsort()` code from the library, is this "legal", following the C/C++-Std?

Comment: yes, it is legal. An implementation of a Standard conforming C compiler is required to supply the functionality described. For example, `qsort` can be written in COBOL (it COBOL can take (void*) parameters) and be conformant. The Standard accepts an implementation to take 2 months to compile the most basic `qsort` example you can find :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible, at least with the way a traditional tool-chain works. The traditional order of operations is that all compilation is done, then linking is done.

To generate your comparison function inline, the compiler would first have to generate the code for `qsort` itself inline (since each instance of `qsort` will usually use a different comparison function). In the case of something like `qsort`, however, it's typically been compiled and placed in the standard library before you ever even start to think about writing your code. When you compile your code, `qsort` is only available as an object file.

As such, to even stand a chance of doing anything like this, you need to build the inlining capability into the *linker* rather than the compiler. At least in theory that's possible, but it's decidedly non-trivial -- at least in my estimation, it's almost certainly more difficult than when working with source code. It also requires duplicating quite a bit of compiler-like functionality in the linker, *and* probably requires adding a fair amount of extra information into the object file to give the linker enough information to work with that it can even try to do the job.

Edit: perhaps I should go into more detail, lest the comment chain turn into a full-fledged argument over little more than wording.

Traditionally, a linker is fundamentally a *fairly* simple sort of beast. It starts from an object file that can be divided into four primary things:

1. A collection of bits that are to be copied (unchanged, except as specifically directed) from the object file to the executable being produced.
2. A list of symbols that the object file contains.
3. A list of symbols used by not supplied by the object file.
4. A list of fixups where addresses need to be written.

the linker then starts matching up the symbols exported in one file and used in another. It then looks in the object files in the library (or libraries) to resolve more symbols. Any time it adds in a file, it also adds *its* list of needed symbols, and searches recursively for other object files that can satisfy those.

When it has found object files that supply all the symbols, it copies the collection of bits part of each into the output file, and where the fixup records tell it to, it writes the relative addresses assigned to specific symbols (e.g., where you've called `printf`, it figures out where in the executable file it copied the bits that make up `printf`, and fills in your call with that address). In reasonably recent cases, rather than copying bits from the library it can embed a reference to a shared object/DLL into the executable, and leave it to the loader to actually find/load that file at run-time to supply the actual code for a symbol.

In particular, however, the linker is traditionally oblivious to the actual content of the blocks of bits it's copying. You can (for example) quite reasonably use exactly the same linker to deal with code for any of a number of different processors. As long as they all use the same object and executable file formats, it's fine.

Link time optimization does change that to at least some degree. Clearly, to optimize the code, we need some sort of extra intelligence that happens at what was traditionally considered link time. There are (at least) two ways to do that:

1. build quite a bit of extra intelligence into the linker
2. keep the intelligence in the compiler, and have the linker invoke it to do the optimization.

There are examples of both of those -- LLVM (for one obvious example) takes pretty much the former. The front-end compiler emits LLVM codes, and LLVM puts a lot of intelligence/work into translating that to an optimized executable. gcc with GIMPLE takes the latter route: the GIMPLE records basically give the linker enough information that it can feed the bits in a number of object files back to the compiler, have the compiler optimize them, and then feed the result back to the linker to actually copy into the executable.

I suppose you can probably come up with some sort of philosophical viewpoint that says these two are basically equivalent -- but I kind of doubt that anybody who'd implemented both would agree.

Now, it is true (probably, anyway) that either of those would suffice to implement the optimization at hand. Personally, I doubt that anybody implements this optimization for its own sake though. When you get down to it, `qsort` and `bsearch` are almost the only two reasonably common functions to which it would/will normally apply. For most practical purposes, that means you'd be implementing the optimization exclusively for the sake of `qsort`.

On the other hand, if the tools involved include the ability to produce inline functions and link time optimization, then I suppose there's at least a reasonable chance that you could end up with this particular type of optimization happening as a more or less accidental side-effect of the two coming together.

At least in theory, that means it could happen. There's one more wrinkle to take into account though: completely independent of the optimization at hand, many compilers will *not* generate inline code for a recursive function. To even attempt to, the compiler has to first convert the recursive function to an iterative form. That's fairly common in the case of tail recursion -- but Quick sort is not tail recursive. Nearly the only alternative is an implementation of `qsort` that isn't recursive to start with. That's certainly possible, but just as certainly rather unusual.

As such, even when/if the toolchain *could* support inline generation of a callback, it probably won't in the case of `qsort` (which, I'll admit, is the only case I've personally tested). For better or worse, however, `qsort` is nearly the only function of this sort that's common enough for it to matter much either.

Comment: Your description mirrors exactly my understanding. Thx. Anyone here who is a compiler writer or language designer who disagrees? Maybe with very recent developments...? gcc5, or MSVC 12...? :-)

Comment: @Jerry: link-time optimizations are not only possible in theory, they are actually available in practice (at least for gcc and llvm); so your initial statement ("it's not possible") is somewhat suspect: it's 'only' a detail of your libc implementation...

Comment: VC++9 and later boasts Link-Time Code Generation that might be able to resolve this, however I haven't tried.

Comment: @Christoph, @sharptooth: While *some* link-time optimization is available, at least in the testing I've done, this one does not seem to be.

Comment: @Jerry: I don't have a gcc version with lto available on this machine; however, I just did a quick test with llvm and it does indeed handle such optimizations at link-time using `clang -emit-llvm -c` and `llvm-ld`; thus, you could probably get an inlineable `qsort()` via linking against a custom libc build...

Comment: @Christoph: Congratulations, you've just confirmed that LLVM isn't a "traditional tool-chain." And yes, what's sent from the front-end to LLVM is a fair amount different from a traditional object file...

Comment: @Jerry: no suprise there - ANY toolchain supporting LTO is 'non-traditional'; emitting llvm bitcode instead of object-code is no more special than adding GIMPLE sections to the object file...

Comment: @Christoph: Given that a linker traditionally did no optimization, I suppose it's a tautology that any linker that does optimization is somewhat non-traditional. OTOH, GIMPLE records only keep the linker simple by re-invoking the compiler at link time, so even though the file doesn't change all that much, the tool-chain does (i.e., what happens at link-time clearly does involve compiler-like intelligence). The same is true with LLVM: you need compiler-like intelligence to convert LLVM bit-codes to "real" executable code.

Comment: @Jerry: Thank you for your very elaborate answer. I got a lot out of that. Basically explaining very detailed what I had just "a feeling" for before. Thanks a lot! Can I give a double-vote-up here? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are compilers which inline callbacks. GCC definitely can do this for functions which are defined in the same compilation unit, and possibly when using LTO (which I did not verify, but there's nothing which prevents such an optimization in principle).

However, whether or not this is possible for `qsort()` is an implementation detail of your standard library: Any standard library function may be provided as an `inline` function - in fact, they actually may be shadowed by function-like macros - and thus the compiler is free to generate a specialized version with inlined calls to the comparison function if this is the case.

Comment: Really? Inlining callbacks with LTO? I would not have thought that. Does the compiler really know, that the pointer to that function will never change? Is there some const semantics on that level? Hmmm...

Comment: @towi: the compiler would have to create new code for each version of the function with statically known callback argument, same as if you used C++ generics; there's no need for whole-program analysis or const semantics here: only the value of the callback argument at the time of funtion invocation is relevant, and if that value is known at compile-time, that's enough to make inlining at least theoretically possible, even at link-time - though it might well be the case the no existing toolchain actually does the necessary object-code duplication...

Comment: @towi: I didn't think of it in terms of partial evaluation/constant propagation when I wrote my answer, but yes, that's a valid point-of-view...

Answer (score 1):

The case you state is one of the multiple reasons you should use functors in C++ over function pointers.

If the compiler is able to inline a function with a callback is rather complex and often depends on various circumstances.

In some trivial example as yours the compiler surely could inline the call as it is able to determine which function will be called. In other programs the function to be called could depend on some runtime parameter, there could be aliasing which the compiler could not detect and whatever black magic the optimizer is using.